# Need help understanding the output

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
    private:
        Base() {
            cout<<"Base ctor has been called "<<endl;
        };
    public:
        int a;
};

class Derived: public Base {

};

int main() {
    Base* b1;
    Derived d1();
    cout<<d1;
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure how the derived class object d1 is created in the above example. The code compiles and run without any error. What type of constructor is getting called while creating `Derived d1();` ? and why output of the `cout<<d1;` is coming as 1? Would the instance of Derived have `int a` of base class? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: `Derived d1();` declares `d1` as a *function* taking no arguments and returning a `Derived` object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ah I see! Sounds good to me. Why output is 1 for the cout part tho?

Comment: It's a little complicated, but all functions are considered "true", which means it's the `bool` overload of `operator<<` which is called with a `true` value. And unless the `boolalpha` flag is set it will be printed as `1`.

Comment: [I recommend turning up your warning level.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TxsTcozad)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your `main` function, `Derived d1();` is actually a declaration of a function called `d1` that takes no arguments and returns a `Derived`. As for why this prints `1`, `std::ostream` has no overload for a `Derived (*)()` (which `d1` is implicitly converted to) so it converts it to the only suitable type, which is a `bool`. Try replacing `cout<<d1;` with `cout << boolalpha << d1;` and you'll see that the program prints `true`.

Comment: [The most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) is a little different, it happens when (believed) constructor arguments are treated as function declaration arguments.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so the most vexing parse only applies when there are arguments to the declaration? (As a side note, I ran this through before posting to test, an the compiler did indeed give a `-Wvexing-parse` warning, which, to me, confirmed my assumption)

Comment: This might belong to the same warning category, for the compiler but isn't really all that *vexing*. Not like e.g. `Class1 obj_but_really_fun(Class2(foo));`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude removed the first sentence, thanks.